# Side effects of not including CommandType for dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, dynamic-sql, parameterized

What pitfalls may I encounter by not setting the cmd.CommandType attribute when running a dynamic sql call?  I can not use adovbs.inc, and using `cmd.CommandType = 200`  yields the error:

> ADODB.Command (0x800A0BB9) Arguments
>   are of the wrong type, are out of
>   acceptable range, or are in conflict
>   with one another.

So by commenting this line out, everything appears to be working as planned.  However, what issues may I run into?

Here is a snippet of the code, for context.

```
        Dim cmd
        Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        cmd.ActiveConnection = dbConn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE active = 1 AND username=? AND password=?"
        cmd.CommandType = 200 'advarchar
        cmd.Parameters(0) = request.form("username")
        cmd.Parameters(1) = request.form("password")
        Dim RS
        Set RS = cmd.Execute()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
cmd.CommandType = 200 ' adVarChar
```

Are you sure you don't want

```
cmd.CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText
```

instead?

Comment: You are correct, haha.  Thank you for that.  What does this line do for me, if when I exclude it, everything still seems functionally correct?

Comment: See <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678358(VS.85).aspx">CommandType Property (ADO)</a> and 
<a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675946(VS.85).aspx">CommandTypeEnum</a>.